# NoReverseMatch when trying to use get_absolute_url with custom template tag

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-urls

I am making a calendar app which has a custom template tag that takes the python HTML template function and overlays objects from the Events model on the correct days. I am trying to get the displayed objects to have a link directly to an object detail/edit view and am trying to use get_absolute_url and to reverse render this view. This is necessary as the custom template tag doesn't load correctly if I try to hardcode `{% url %}` template tags into it for each event via a for loop. I have spent some hours looking through the other stack overflow questions with no luck and have even changed my reverse to the object ID rather than the title of the event. I am hoping this is just a small thing that I have overlooked but no sure.

view:

```
def home(request, month=None, year=None):
    if month == None:
        _date = datetime.now()
    else:
        _date = date(int(year), int(month), 1)
    title = "%s, %s" % (_date.strftime("%B"), _date.strftime("%Y"))

    return render(request, 'calendar.html', calendar(_date, title))
```

url:

```
app_name = 'cal'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^newevent/$', views.newEvent, name='newevent'),
    url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)$/', views.viewEvent, name='viewevent'),
    url(r'^(?P<month>\d+)/(?P<year>\d+)$', views.home, name='another-month')
]
```

HTML:

```
    <div>
      {% load calendarify %}
      <span id="calendarify">{% calendarify year month event_list %}</span>
    </div>
```

Template tag:

```
def do_month_calendarify(parser, token):
    # Take the tag input from the template and format
    # Template syntax is {% calendarify year month %}
    try:
        tag_name, year, month, event_list = token.split_contents()
    except ValueError:
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError(
            "%r tag requires three arguments" % token.contents.split()[0]
        )
    return CalendarifyNode(year, month, event_list)

class CalendarifyNode(template.Node):

    def __init__(self, year, month, event_list):
        try:
            self.year = template.Variable(year)
            self.month = template.Variable(month)
            self.event_list = template.Variable(event_list)
        except ValueError:
            raise template.TemplateSyntaxError

    def render(self, context):
        try:
            my_year = self.year.resolve(context)
            my_month = self.month.resolve(context)
            my_event_list = self.event_list.resolve(context)
            cal = EventCalendar(my_event_list)
            return cal.formatmonth(
                int(my_year), int(my_month))
        except ValueError:
            return "%s, %s, %s" % (my_month, my_year, my_event_list)

class EventCalendar(HTMLCalendar):
    # Use Python's HTMLCalendar and put user events over top
    def __init__(self, events):
        super(EventCalendar, self).__init__()
        self.events = self.group_by_day(events)

    def formatday(self, day, weekday):
        if day != 0:
            cssid = self.cssclasses[weekday]
            cssclass = "daybox"
            if date.today() == date(self.year, self.month, day):
                cssid += ' today'
            if day in self.events:
                cssid += ' filled'
                body = ['<ul>']
                for event in self.events[day]:
                    body.append('<li>')
                    body.append('<a href="%s">' % event.get_absolute_url())
                    body.append(esc(event.title))
                    body.append('</a></li>')
                body.append('</ul>')
                return self.day_cell(
                    cssclass, cssid, '<span class="dayNumber">%d</span> %s' % (
                        day, ''.join(body)))
            return self.day_cell(
                cssclass, cssid, '<span class="dayNumberNoReadings">%d</span>' % (day))
        return self.day_cell('nodaybox', 'noday', '&nbsp;')

    def formatmonth(self, year, month):
        self.year, self.month = year, month
        return super(EventCalendar, self).formatmonth(year, month)

    def group_by_day(self, events):
        field = lambda event: event.start_date.day
        return dict(
            [(day, list(items)) for day, items in groupby(events, field)]
        )

    def day_cell(self, cssclass, cssid, body):
        return '<td class="%s" id="%s">%s</td>' % (cssclass, cssid, body)

register.tag('calendarify', do_month_calendarify)
```

Model:

```
class Events(models.Model):
    ...

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('cal:viewEvent', args=[str(self.id)], current_app='cal')
```

Sorry about the load of code posted. Any chance anyone knows what might have caused this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by a typo/mismatch between the following:

```
url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)$/', views.viewEvent, name='viewevent'),
```

name = viewevent

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
return reverse('cal:viewEvent', args=[str(self.id)],
current_app='cal')
```

name = viewEvent

Once these were corrected it worked fine.